# OpenMP parallel for - what is default schedule?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

What schedule algorithm is used when no `schedule` clause is specified? I.e.:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    Foo(i);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start from the [documentation](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) that you have linked to. Section **2.7.1.1 Determining the Schedule of a Worksharing Loop** reads:

> If the loop directive does not have a **schedule** clause then the current value of the *def-sched-var* ICV determines the schedule.

The sentence preceding the quoted one refers to Section 2.3.1 which reads:

> - *def-sched-var* - controls the implementation defined default scheduling of loop regions. There is one copy of this ICV per device.

The table in Section **2.3.2 ICV Initialization** states that the initial value of *def-sched-var* is implementation defined and that there is no environment variable that affects that value. Therefore the default loop schedule is implementation defined. Q.E.D.