# How will the threads be scheduled when their number is greater than the number of iterations?

Tags: openmp

I am a beginner to OpenMP. There are some loops in my code and they have different number of iterations.
I set the number of threads as the greatest number of iterations among these loops. 
But what will happen when the number of threads is greater than the number of iterations for some of my loops?

The code to specify the number of threads is

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads
```

Comment: Without a more specific example of what you mean, my response would be that the threads which have no work assigned will go idle while the others complete.

Comment: If you don't employ a schedule clause, and don't set the default scheduling ICV it is implementation defined. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291581/openmp-parallel-for-what-is-default-schedule

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that when you say "number of loops" you mean "number of iterations in a loop", then the answer should be fairly clear!

Consider

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(10)
#pragma omp for
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    ...
```

There are only five iterations, so the largest number of threads that can execute an iteration is also five (if each of them executes one iteration), and, therefore, at least five threads will immediately skip to the implicit barrier at the end of the for loop.

However, I get the impression that what you're doing is trying to adjust the number of threads in each parallel region to match the number of iterations. That is a **bad** idea. Changing the number of threads (the team size) is a s..l..o..w operation.

Indeed, it is generally a bad idea to set the number of threads explicitly at all. In general the OpenMP runtime will set the number of threads appropriately for the hardware on which the program is running. You don't need to force the number of threads yourself unless you are doing scaling tests, in which case using the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable is still easier!

Forcing the number of threads "because my machine has that many cores" prompts these questions

1. Will you have that machine for the rest of your life?
2. Are you the only person who will ever run this code?