# OpenMP for loop sequentailly in parallel

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm looking to multithread a for loop using OpenMP.
As I understood when you do a loop like;

```cpp
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NTHREADS)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    ...
```

All the threads will just grab an i and move on with their work.
For my implementation, I need to have it that they work "sequentially" in parallel.
By that I mean that e.g., for a length of 800 with 8 threads, I need thread 1 to work on 0 to 99, thread 2 to work on 100-199 and so on.

Is this possible with OpenMP?

Answer (score 3):

Your desired behavior is the default. The loop can be scheduled in several ways, and `schedule(static)` is the default: the loop gets divided in blocks, and the first thread takes the first block, et cetera.

So your initial understanding was wrong: a thread does not grab an index, but a block.

Just to note: if you want a thread to grab a smaller block, you can specify `schedule(static,8)` or whatever number suits you, but less than 8 runs into cache performance problems.

Comment: I don't think the OpenMP specification guarantees that the default provides the requested chunking of iterations (I don't think matters have changed since https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291581/openmp-parallel-for-what-is-default-schedule).  That said, I'm not sure that any implementation I've ever used did not default to a static schedule

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Point taken. I was describing the common case.

Answer (score 2):

From [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu48.html#x73-730002.11.4):

> `schedule([modifier [, modifier]:]kind[, chunk_size])`

> When kind is *static*, iterations are divided into chunks of size
> *chunk_size*, and the chunks are assigned to the threads in the team in
> a round-robin fashion in the order of the thread number. Each chunk
> contains *chunk_size* iterations, except for the chunk that contains the
> sequentially last iteration, which may have fewer iterations. When no
> *chunk_size* is specified, the iteration space is divided into chunks
> that are **approximately** equal in size, and at most one chunk is
> distributed to each thread. The size of the chunks is unspecified in
> this case.
>
> When the *monotonic* modifier is specified then each thread executes the
> chunks that it is assigned in increasing logical iteration order.
>
> For a team of *p* threads and a loop of *n* iterations, let *n∕p* be the
> integer *q* that satisfies *n = p * q - r*, with *0 <= r < p*. One compliant
> implementation of the *static* schedule (**with no specified *chunk_size***)
> would behave as though *chunk_size* had been specified with value *q*.
> Another compliant implementation would assign *q* iterations to the
> first *p - r* threads, and *q - 1* iterations to the remaining *r* threads.
> This illustrates why a conforming **program must not rely on the details
> of a particular implementation**.

The default schedule is taken from [def-sched-var](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu31.html#x50-680002.5.2) and it is implementation defined, so if your program relies on it, define it explicitly:

```
schedule(monotonic:static,chunk_size)
```

In this case it is clearly defined how your program behaves and does not depend on the implementation at all. Note also that your code should not depend on the number of threads, because OpenMP does not guarantee that your parallel region gets all the requested/available threads. Note also that the `monotonic` modifier is the default in the case of `static` schedule, so you do not have to state it explicitly.

So, if the above mentioned 'approximate' chunk size or the exact number of threads is not an issue in your case, your code should be

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) num_threads(NTHREADS)
```

On the other hand, if you need a control on chunk_size and/or on the exact number of threads used, you should use something like

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(NTHREADS)
{
  #pragma omp single
  {
    int nthreads=omp_get_num_threads();
      //calculate chunk_size based on nthreads
      chunk_size=.....
  }

  #pragma omp for schedule(static,chunk_size) 
  for(...)
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what advantage your code gains by calculating the chunk size and setting it explicitly.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I do not know what the OP's aim exactly is. Consider if `length=800` and `NTHREADS=8`, but `nthreads=4` only in practice and the program expects that thread 1 works on i= 0 to 99, it may cause problem. If this issue is important, the OP should calculate it this way, otherwise just use `schedule(static)`

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you for the comment, I have edited my answer to be more clear.